# Issue with Team Explorer Everywhere on MAC OS

Tags: eclipse, macos, xamarin, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to use TFS for code checkin and checkout on MAC using Eclipse. I have recently moved to a new MAC system with `Mojave`, older one used to work fine with `Team Explorer Everywhere` and `Eclipse Neon 3`.

I am using the following version of Eclipse and using the latest version of `Team Explorer Everywhere 14.134.0` plugin.

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
```

I get the following error when I try to open the TEE  `Plug-in "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui" was unable to instantiate class "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.views.TeamExplorerView"`

I have the JAVA Version `java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16`

Can someone help ?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: version.inin file is their , which has following details

#Sun May 19 20:24:43 IST 2019
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.11.0.v20190307-0500